# Error:(512) *** non-numeric second argument to `wordlist' function: '16z'. Stop

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I have been following some tutorials on how to uses opencv and ndk in Android Studio. I have tried out all possible solutions given on Stack Overflow. Below is my build.gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "medianet.com.helloopencv"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
}
task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    commandLine "C:/Users/firas/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd",
            'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
            'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
            'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
            'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

    dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation project(':openCVLibrary330')
}
```

Comment: Have you look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131691/non-numeric-second-argument-to-wordlist)?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the solution was pretty easy, it was my fault , all i  need it to do is to go to Android.mk file and change :  APP_PLATFORM := android-16z to  APP_PLATFORM := android-16.